# GitHub Actions - Ignore or exclude Dependabot Pull Requests

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, dependabot

I have a repository with **Dependabot** in it, that opens PR on version updates, etc which I would like to keep.

In the same repository, I have a GitHub Action for Pull Requests for my team to use.

My issue is that the Dependabot keeps triggering the Pull Request action no matter what I tried.

My PR action have to be triggered on staging branch pull requests, like so:

```
name: Pull Request
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
```

So I can't use both on pull_reuqest AND branches_ignore - as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore)

Workflow attempts I have tried so far that unfortunately haven't worked:

```
name: Pull Request
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
      - '!dependabot/**'
```

---

```
name: Pull Request
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  Build:
    if: github.actor!= 'dependabot-preview[bot]'
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

---

I have also tried excluding the Dependabot user like so:

```
if: github.actor!= 'depbot'
```

Would love some insights or answers on how you have dealt with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you print the `github.actor`, like so: `- run: echo ${{ github.actor }}`. What does it say?

Comment: You may want to check if dependabot is triggering other workflow conditions like `push`. When it creates PR, that could be counted as a push to your repository too, that's what happened in my case.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I guess there were many changes over the years and you can find outdated ways all over the web. The actual way is [documented in the Dependabot documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions)

```
if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' }}
```

Note that nowadays you can also check the [`github.triggering_actor`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) - if you want workflow to be skipped if Dependabot triggered it, but want to be able to manually trigger it on a PR that was opened by Dependabot.

Comment: Here's a link to the section with the conditional check: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/automating-dependabot-with-github-actions#common-dependabot-automations